# Invariance of Integration on Homotopic Curves

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

All:

I'm trying to show that if curves $\gamma, \gamma'$ are homotopic to each other in some region $R$ (open, connected subset) of the plane, and f is differentiable in $R$ , then:

$\int_{\gamma}f=\int_{\gamma'}f$ .

Please critique this argument and help me finish: first, we construct a homotopy $H(x,t)$ between the two curves  ${\gamma},{\gamma'}$, with $H(x,0)=\gamma, H(x,1)=\gamma'$ then, define $M$ to be the set $H(x,t)$for $t$ in $(0,1)$, so that $M$ is the region bounded by the two curves.

Now, we apply Stokes' thm. to get:

$\int \int_M df=\int_{\partial M} f=\int_{\gamma}f-\int_{\gamma'}f$

Now, I need to have the integral be equal to zero, to get the equality

$\int_{\gamma}f-\int_{\gamma'}f=0$

How can I do so? Is the rest correct?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is $f$? A vector field/one-form? You need $f$ to be closed/conservative (i.e. $df=0$) as an assumption for this to be true - try out some examples.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony, don't mean to leave you hanging, but I need to get myself to sleep; it is 4a.m here. I will be back tomorrow.